# How can I check for the existance of an enum value in an array of Enums?

Tags: c#

I have this code to authorize users:

```
public enum Role {
   Admin,
   User
}

public class AuthorizeRolesAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    private Role[] _roles;
    public AuthorizeRolesAttribute(params Role[] roles)
    {
        _roles = roles;
    }

    protected override bool IsAuthorized(HttpActionContext actionContext)
    {
        ClaimsIdentity claimsIdentity;
        var httpContext = HttpContext.Current;
        if (!(httpContext.User.Identity is ClaimsIdentity))
        {
            return false;
        }

        claimsIdentity = httpContext.User.Identity as ClaimsIdentity;
        var roleId = claimsIdentity.FindFirst("RoleId");

        if (_roles == null)
        {
            // just extra defense, not sure it should happen
            return false;
        }

        // This line fails 
        return _roles.Contains(roleId);
    }
}
```

It checks for the following:

```
[AuthorizeRoles(Role.Admin, Role.User)]
```

However I am getting confused.  _roles contains an array of type Role. and the roleId is a number that represents the role.

My line with contains is failing with this message:

```
Error   2   'Entities.Enums.Role[]' does not contain a definition for 'Contains' 
and the best extension method overload 'System.Linq.Queryable.Contains<TSource>
(System.Linq.IQueryable<TSource>, TSource)' has some invalid arguments
```

How can I make it so roleId is converted into a type of Role so the contains works?

Comment: `FindFirst()` returns an object of type `Claim`, not `int`.

Comment: Check if this helps:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4034938/how-to-use-linq-contains-to-find-a-list-of-enums

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The contains method requires an enum value

If your roldeId is an integer.

You could use

```
 _roles.Contains((Role)roleId);
```

If its a string you would need to use `Enum.Parse` and `Enum.IsDefined` methods.

here is a small snippet:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Role[] _roles;
        _roles = new[] {Role.Admin, Role.User};

        Console.WriteLine( _roles.Contains((Role)0)); // True
        Console.WriteLine(_roles.Contains((Role)1)); // True
        Console.WriteLine(_roles.Contains((Role)2)); // False

        Role role = (Role)Enum.Parse(typeof (Role), "Admin");
        Console.WriteLine(_roles.Contains(role)); // True
    }

    public enum Role
    {
        Admin,
        User,
        Guest
    }
}
```

Hope this helps

Comment: what is it then a string?

Comment: it's a `Claim`. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh159719(v=vs.110).aspx.

Comment: Claim.Value is the string value of the Claim according to the link you've posted

Answer (score 0):

If your id is a string you can write it like this:

```
var roleId = "Admin";
var roleEnum = (Role)Enum.Parse(typeof(Role), roleId);
return _roles.Contains(roleEnum);
```